# jax.lax.fori_loop Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected

Tags: jax

I've a JAX loop that looks like this where inside the step function I use `min` between the two arguments

```py
import jax

def step(timestep: int, order: int = 4) -> int:
    order = min(timestep + 1, order)
    return order

num_steps = 10
order = 100
order = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, num_steps, step, order)
```

The above code fails with a `jax._src.errors.ConcretizationTypeError`. This is is the full stacktrace:

```py
WARNING:jax._src.lib.xla_bridge:No GPU/TPU found, falling back to CPU. (Set TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0 and rerun for more info.)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnfilteredStackTrace                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9ec280f437cb> in <module>
      2 order = 100
----> 3 order = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, num_steps, step, order)

16 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/_src/traceback_util.py in reraise_with_filtered_traceback(*args, **kwargs)
    161     try:
--> 162       return fun(*args, **kwargs)
    163     except Exception as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/loops.py in fori_loop(lower, upper, body_fun, init_val)
   1691 
-> 1692     (_, result), _ = scan(_fori_scan_body_fun(body_fun), (lower_, init_val),
   1693                           None, length=upper_ - lower_)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/_src/traceback_util.py in reraise_with_filtered_traceback(*args, **kwargs)
    161     try:
--> 162       return fun(*args, **kwargs)
    163     except Exception as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/loops.py in scan(f, init, xs, length, reverse, unroll)
    258   # necessary, a second time with modified init values.
--> 259   init_flat, carry_avals, carry_avals_out, init_tree, *rest = _create_jaxpr(init)
    260   new_init_flat, changed = _promote_weak_typed_inputs(init_flat, carry_avals, carry_avals_out)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/loops.py in _create_jaxpr(init)
    244     carry_avals = tuple(_map(_abstractify, init_flat))
--> 245     jaxpr, consts, out_tree = _initial_style_jaxpr(
    246         f, in_tree, (*carry_avals, *x_avals), "scan")

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/common.py in _initial_style_jaxpr(fun, in_tree, in_avals, primitive_name)
     59                          primitive_name: Optional[str] = None):
---> 60   jaxpr, consts, out_tree = _initial_style_open_jaxpr(
     61       fun, in_tree, in_avals, primitive_name)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/common.py in _initial_style_open_jaxpr(fun, in_tree, in_avals, primitive_name)
     53   debug = pe.debug_info(fun, in_tree, False, primitive_name or "<unknown>")
---> 54   jaxpr, _, consts = pe.trace_to_jaxpr_dynamic(wrapped_fun, in_avals, debug)
     55   return jaxpr, consts, out_tree()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/_src/profiler.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    313     with TraceAnnotation(name, **decorator_kwargs):
--> 314       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    315     return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/interpreters/partial_eval.py in trace_to_jaxpr_dynamic(fun, in_avals, debug_info, keep_inputs)
   1980     main.jaxpr_stack = ()  # type: ignore
-> 1981     jaxpr, out_avals, consts = trace_to_subjaxpr_dynamic(
   1982       fun, main, in_avals, keep_inputs=keep_inputs, debug_info=debug_info)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/interpreters/partial_eval.py in trace_to_subjaxpr_dynamic(fun, main, in_avals, keep_inputs, debug_info)
   1997     in_tracers_ = [t for t, keep in zip(in_tracers, keep_inputs) if keep]
-> 1998     ans = fun.call_wrapped(*in_tracers_)
   1999     out_tracers = map(trace.full_raise, ans)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/linear_util.py in call_wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs)
    166     try:
--> 167       ans = self.f(*args, **dict(self.params, **kwargs))
    168     except:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/loops.py in scanned_fun(loop_carry, _)
   1607     i, x = loop_carry
-> 1608     return (i + 1, body_fun()(i, x)), None
   1609   return scanned_fun

<ipython-input-2-2e3345899235> in step(timestep, order)
      1 def step(timestep: int, order: int = 100) -> int:
----> 2     order = min(timestep + 1, order)
      3     return order

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/core.py in __bool__(self)
    633   def __nonzero__(self): return self.aval._nonzero(self)
--> 634   def __bool__(self): return self.aval._bool(self)
    635   def __int__(self): return self.aval._int(self)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/core.py in error(self, arg)
   1266   def error(self, arg):
-> 1267     raise ConcretizationTypeError(arg, fname_context)
   1268   return error

UnfilteredStackTrace: jax._src.errors.ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected: Traced<ShapedArray(bool[], weak_type=True)>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>
The problem arose with the `bool` function. 
The error occurred while tracing the function scanned_fun at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/loops.py:1606 for scan. This concrete value was not available in Python because it depends on the values of the argument 'loop_carry'.

See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.ConcretizationTypeError

The stack trace below excludes JAX-internal frames.
The preceding is the original exception that occurred, unmodified.

--------------------

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ConcretizationTypeError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9ec280f437cb> in <module>
      1 num_steps = 10
      2 order = 100
----> 3 order = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, num_steps, step, order)

<ipython-input-2-2e3345899235> in step(timestep, order)
      1 def step(timestep: int, order: int = 100) -> int:
----> 2     order = min(timestep + 1, order)
      3     return order

ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected: Traced<ShapedArray(bool[], weak_type=True)>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>
The problem arose with the `bool` function. 
The error occurred while tracing the function scanned_fun at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/loops.py:1606 for scan. This concrete value was not available in Python because it depends on the values of the argument 'loop_carry'.

See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.ConcretizationTypeError
```

Everything works fine if instead of using `jax.lax.fori_loop` i use a simple python loop, but my original code will end up very slow. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jax.numpy.minimum` in place of `min`:

```py
def step(timestep: int, order: int = 4) -> int:
    order = jax.numpy.minimum(timestep + 1, order)
    return order
```

The reason `min` does not work is that in the course of executing code within `jit`, `grad`, `vmap`, `fori_loop`, etc., JAX replaces concrete values with abstract tracers, and Python functions like `min` don't know how to handle these abstract values. See [How to Think in JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/thinking_in_jax.html) for more background on this.

Comment: thanks that was helpful. I think they should do a better job with the error messages!

Comment: The error message is already pretty detailed. What information would have helped you?

Comment: it is mis-leading I thought it was an issue with the arguments, but it turns out it is related to the function

Comment: What specifically do you think the error message could have said that would have communicated that more clearly? It already says "the problem arose with the bool function", because internally `min` calls `bool`, and this is where the problem arises.

Comment: wonder if it could be possible for trivial cases like this one, to print a recommendation for using jax.numpy functions instead of python standard ones.

Comment: between thats' my first jax program, i was copying snippets here and there to get something to work

Comment: I see - thanks. The problem is it's actually quite hard in general to write such an error message, because all the code sees here is that the `__bool__` method was called on a traced array. Trying to inspect the stack trace and infer anything deeper than that is quite challenging to do in a general robust way. That's why I chose to link within the error message to a help page that describes specific situations where that specific error might come up. Out of curiosity, did you follow that link? I'll try to update that help page to be more helpful.

Comment: yeah I did follow the link, it describes well what the error mean and that's why I thought the problem was related to the arguments not that I cannot use `min`